# Prestashop1.7 how to configure avaliable fields in import of advanced parameters

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am trying to import category or product information from external csv file using Advanced parameter/import.
In this case, when i am tryng to import product csv file,
As a standard form, it requires a lot of available fields such as ID~ Accesories.
How can i configure these fields so that i can use necessary or less fields.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c64rF.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you import a new CSV file, you have to select the right fields (so Product ID has to match Product ID, and so on) to create a proper import. You can also choose to skip a field if you feel you don't need to import them. You can find documentation on it [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Import)

Comment: thanks for your answer.
But i know it.
what i want to know is that can i remove the fields so that only necessary fields are left.

Comment: Programmatically you can remove anything you want, but there are no "standard" required fields which you can add or remove by configuration. The only thing you can do is select the value "do not import this field" (or what's it called...) in the dropdown. And you can save the template so you can use it again later. But why would you want to go through all that efford to remove those fields if you only need to use the import function once or twice?